# Remove Views from a table layout except the header in android?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout where I am populating the data to table row from webservice. I have a refresh button, onclick of which I get different data, but my question is when once the data is loaded, and I try to re populate the new data, it gets appended at bottom of previous data. I want to clear previous data and load the new one replacing the old one. I have used **tablelayout.removeallviews();** , but then it also clears my header. I dont to clear the header, only the data should get replaced.[image]

Now the blue row also gets removed ,when I use removeallviews() method. I want to keep as it is and replace the below data with new one.

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) is better than what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ListView to populate your data in the second row of your table (make only 2 rows table, header and data). When you want to refres, clear the adapter, add the new data and call `adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()`.

[Here](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php) you have simple ListView example.

If you want to have different columns for every row in your ListView you need a custom layout for it. Check [this](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html) example.

Comment: My table scrolls vertically and horizontally.

Comment: You didn't mentioned that in your question. Anyway ListView only scrolls vertically. Maybe if you search more in this forum you can find a way to do it scroll horizontally. Good luck!